# How can I align the content in the 2nd column using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I would like to align the content in the 2nd column to look like this:
[image: desired look]

Currently, it is looking like this:
[image: current look]

I believed it has got to do with my flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis. but I am not sure. Here is the JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/onestaryx/c70yg2t9/2/

```
.work-meta-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-self: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  line-height: 22px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  .work-meta-label{
    font-weight: bold;
    flex-basis: 200px;
  }
  .work-meta-value{
    flex-grow:1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please add a [mcve] to your post.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
      .work-meta-row{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-start;
        align-self: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        line-height: 22px;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        .work-meta-label{
          font-weight: bold;
          flex: 0 0 200px;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

flex grow and flex shrink are ON i.e. 1 by default. You need to disable it to match the UI you require. This is how you can do it:

```
`.work-meta-row {
    display: flex;
    line-height: 22px;

    .work-meta-label {
        font-weight: bold;
        flex-grow: 0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        flex-basis: 100px;
    }
}`
```

OR use with the flex shorthand like:

```
`.work-meta-row {
    display: flex;
    line-height: 22px;

    .work-meta-label {
        font-weight: bold;
        flex: 0 0 100px;
    }
}`
```

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please mark this as correct answer if the solution satisfied your requirement?

Comment: I did but I sadly I got not enough reputation so my votes didn't count :P

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. Not a problem.